# How to make my REST API unaware about my frontend URL schema

Tags: rest, web-applications, architecture

My webapp is a REST API + separate frontend with its own routing.

I want to create an Excel report about a user, so I pass `user_id` to the report creation endpoint in my API. The endpoint embeds a link like `http://www.some_frontend.com/users/<user_id>` in the created Excel report.

That's an issue to me, because my API now needs to know the URL structure of the (theoretically separate) frontend and I need to keep the two in sync if the frontend URL ever changes.

If my frontend was the only client to this API endpoint, I could pass the user link to the endpoint from the frontend directly. But there are also other clients to this endpoint that don't know anything about the fronted URL structure.

Is there any pattern to work around that?

Comment: If the excel file is not persisted, you could simply copy the Host header.

Comment: why not just pass in the domain as part of the report creation? e.g. "http://www.some_frontend.com". Arguably, you're creating a new Report Resource so POST to /api/report with the user_id and the domain in the body. The API can then use the domain parameter to prefix the embedded link.

Comment: @codebrane: The thing is not all API clients calling this endpoint will know the domain, only the frontend, so the endpoint cannot rely on receiving the URL from the client.